# sql loader : Load string greater than 4000 characters using sql loader

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I need to load a CSV file into table using sql loader but the lenth of a column is exceeding the Max length of varchar2 data type.

Create table statement :

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST_PIPE_SEP (FILE_NM VARCHAR2(3000), KEY_COL VARCHAr2(4000), DESCR VARCHAR2(4000), RUN_DATE DATE );
```

CTL file :

```
load data
into table test_pipe_sep
append
fields terminated by ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 FILE_NM char(4000) "trim(:FILE_NM)",
 KEY_COL char(4000) "trim(:KEY_COL)",
 DESCR "trim(:DESCR)",
 RUN_DATE "to_date(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')"
)
```

CSV sample record :

```
sample_file_name.csv,"B"|"STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID"|"TRANCHE_COLLATERAL_TYPE"|"TRANCHE_GUARANTEE_TYPE"|"BS_TYPE"|"CONTRACT_REFERENCE"|"CONTRACT_TYPE"|,Not Present in file2
```

I just not paste the full text here as it will become lengthy but you can append the length of middle column in CSV or KEY_COL field value to more than 4000 for testing.

SQLLDR :

```
sqlldr userid=$SQL_CREDENTIALS control=new_test_3.ctl data=data/$filename log=logs/$filename.log bad=logs/$filename.bad skip=1
```

Please suggest if there is any way where we can load a string of length more than 4000 using SQL LOADER or is there any workaround for this kind of problem.

I am on :

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it ! :)

Change the column data type to CLOB as below :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_PIPE_SEP (FILE_NM VARCHAR2(3000), KEY_COL CLOB, DESCR VARCHAR2(4000), RUN_DATE DATE );
```

Then the CTL I used to load data into CLOB column is as below :

```
load data
into table test_pipe_sep
append
fields terminated by ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 FILE_NM char(4000) "trim(:FILE_NM)",
 KEY_COL CHAR(30000) optionally ENCLOSED BY '<' AND '>',
 DESCR "trim(:DESCR)",
 RUN_DATE "to_date(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried similar ways for a while and finally using the modified code below worked great:

load data into table test_pipe_sep
append:

```
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 FILE_NM char(4000) terminated by ',' ,
 KEY_COL CHAR(30000),
 DESCR terminated by ',' , 
 RUN_DATE "to_date(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')"
)
```